# Can I use raw T-SQL commands in Entity Framework Core to initialize a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core-3.1

Entity Framework Core doesn't seem to support all sorts of constraints applicable to a database column.

In order to add such constraint during database initialization, I need to run a query like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CreatedAt DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR CreatedAt
```

How can I do this in Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Please elaborate on your process of database creation. What keeps you from doing what you want?

Comment: I assumed C#, is that correct?